# Zabbix HTTP agent trim xml

Tags: xml, zabbix

*Good day everyone!*

New Zabbix 4.0 has HTTP agent, so you don't need to execute scripts anymore to get values from web-server.

Right now I have page with answer:

`<boolean class=" FB_FW_ext BlitzScPluginAdapter">true</boolean>`

I need to convert it to true-1 and false-0. I can use trim and Boolean to decimal, but it takes lots of steps (9 steps + 1 to convert).

[image]
Is it possible to make less steps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a regex to extract true or false, something like `<.*>(.*)<.*>$`(see [here](https://regex101.com/r/dBMpll/1)), then use a [value map](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/4.0/manual/config/items/mapping) to convert true and false to 0 and 1

Comment: It Works! I made two preprocession steps: first regular expression <.*>(.*)<.*>$ with parameter \1, and second is boolean to decimal. Thank you so much!